# Django 1.6 with python 3.3 default settings.py file

Tags: django

I have installed django 1.6 with python3.3 on a virtual env...
When i create a project with startproject command i get below:

```
"""
Django settings for ozo project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '***********************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ozo.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ozo.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I think there are some settings missing in this file. I have tested with django 1.5 startproject command and it puts settings like:

MEDIA_URL, STATIC_ROOT, LOGGING, TEMPLATE_DIRS ... etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default project template has been simplified in Django 1.6.You can see an explanation of the changes on the [commit message on GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/commit/3f1c7b70537330435e2ec2fca9550f7b7fa4372e). If you need a setting like `MEDIA_URL`, then add it in.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see from the django 1.6 release

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/docs/releases/1.6.txt

> Simplified default project and app templates
>
> The default templates used by :djadmin:`startproject` and :djadmin:`startapp`
>   have been simplified and modernized. The :doc:`admin
>   </ref/contrib/admin/index>` is now enabled by default in new projects; the
>   :doc:`sites </ref/contrib/sites>` framework no longer is. :ref:`clickjacking
>   prevention <clickjacking-prevention>` is now on and the database defaults to
>   SQLite.
>
> If the default templates don't suit your tastes, you can use :ref:`custom
>   project and app templates <custom-app-and-project-templates>`

So we can just create a app ,such as django-admin.py startapp testapp,and create templates/testapp dir.Then put the html in the test/app/templates/testapp/test.html

we can use the html in the views.py like this

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('testapp/test.html')
```

we should not add anything in the settings.py.